# is there an alternate way to get video tags/keywords in youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

based on http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2012/08/tags-removed-from-video-watch-pages.html, youtube has made media:keywords element empty in youtube api as well.

However, it is important for my application to scan through the tags/keywords. Is there an alternate solution for me to get the tags/keywords for a video?

Comment: I do see its there in video page source. am I to dowload and parse the html page source for that video to get the keywords?

Comment: why was it removed from api if the intent was to protect the average watcher? I dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post gives information relevant to developers: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

You can get the tags if you're authenticated as the owner of the video. Otherwise, no, it's not currently possible.

Comment: but its available in html page source of the video. I can always read that. Then why just take it from api or the other way why not put in api result set as well alongwith html page source